# Generating an alphanumeric Sequence in C# on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, logic

I want to create an alphanumeric number in c#.The format should be

AAA00001
AAA00002
.
.
.
AAA99999
AAB00001
.
AAB99999
.
.
AAZ00001
.
.
ABA00001
.
.
ZZZ99999

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Seems great. What's stopping you? Also, what would be the next value after `ZZZ99999`?

Comment: @Aars93 I have not tried I'm new to c# environment

Comment: @pranaybrahmbhatt Well StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We give support to people who have tried to write their own code but are facing a problem. I would suggest you follow some tutorials about loops and strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication103
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AlphaNumeric alphaNumeric = new AlphaNumeric();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100010; i++)
            {
                string sequence = alphaNumeric.GetSequence();
                Console.WriteLine(sequence);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    public class AlphaNumeric
    {
        const int NUMBER_PLACES = 5;
        int maxInteger = 1;
        Boolean OVER_FLOW = false;
        static string format = new string('0', NUMBER_PLACES);
        private static int number { get; set; }
        private static List<char> alpha { get; set; }

        public AlphaNumeric()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_PLACES ; i++) {maxInteger *= 10;}
            number = 1;
            alpha = new List<char>() { 'A', 'A', 'A' };
        }
        public string GetSequence()
        {
            if(OVER_FLOW) return "OVERFLOW ERROR";
            string sequence = string.Join("", alpha) + number.ToString(format);
            Increment();
            return sequence;
        }
        public void Increment()
        {
            number++;
            if (number >= maxInteger)
            {
                number = 1;

                for (int i = alpha.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    int ascii = (int)alpha[i] + 1;
                    if ((ascii <= (int)'Z'))
                    {
                        alpha[i] = (char)ascii;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            OVER_FLOW = true; ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alpha[i] = 'A';
                        }
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```